# How to get around Tumblr returning it's images embedded in a webpage to a 3rd party service

Tags: twilio, tumblr, twilio-api

Ran into this issue and wanted to share my solution.

I am writing a script that gets images from a Tumblr blog and texts them to me. I was using a web scraper but switched to Tumblr's api, both of which got me the same images hosted on `64.media.tumblr.com`. I ran into an issue when trying to use Twilio to send the images because Twilio wasn't getting an image from the url I provided, instead it got a webpage with the image embedded in it. Here is an [example image](https://64.media.tumblr.com/b3c5cfa0a6e5c937ec16e2ddb07e0855/c48fb2ae3430cbfb-34/s1280x1920/f322b5388a13649bff0802d47ab398ecc7f888b9.jpg) - I find that sometimes it'll initially open as an image, but on refresh I get the webpage. I contemplated converting the image into a base 64 data url, but Twilio wouldn't accept that.

Answer (score 1):

### Tl;dr

Upload the image to a free image hosting site like Imgur ([here's the API](https://apidocs.imgur.com/#:%7E:text=POST-,Image%20Upload,-https%3A//api.imgur), you can just supply the source image url) then use the url from that site.

### My Findings

Through some experimentation I found that I would get the image response when requesting with Axios and Postman, but get the webpage when requesting with Chrome and Puppeteer. This lead me to believe that Tumblr is attempting to only return the webpage to browsers, possibly a User Agent check. Whatever method Twilio is using to request images is triggering Tumblr to send the webpage back. If we can get the image hosted on another site that doesn't do embedding, we can solve our problem. Luckily Imgur exists and has a nice [api](https://apidocs.imgur.com/#:%7E:text=POST-,Image%20Upload,-https%3A//api.imgur) we can use to upload anonymous images. Twilio happily accepted the Imgur image urls.

Comment: If you use the tumblr api you can get data back from the server which includes img src properties. https://i.imgur.com/Dxerdf0.png

Comment: @lharby the problem was not retrieving the img url, it was that making a `GET` request to that img url would return a webpage with an `<img>`, instead of returning the raw image data, which is where Twilio was having the problem. In short, the image url returned content-type `text/html` insead of `image/jpeg`.

Comment: Can you share your code, because firstly there 'might' be a way to force the mime type for image in the response. Secondly your solution for scraping images from tumblr is just to host the images somewhere else, which is sort of sidestepping the issue I think, does this not mean having to post many images to a new hosting site?  Let's see if it can be solved.

Comment: @lharby I'm not the one requesting the image data, Twilio is, so unless there's a way to embed the desired mime type in the image url I give twilio, [via their sms/mms api](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/tutorials/how-to-send-sms-messages-node-js#:~:text=parameter.-,Send%20a%20Message%20with%20an%20Image%20URL,-Again%2C%20update%20the), I see no other option.